# free, cheap or open source UML and Visio-like tool

Tags: uml, diagram, flowchart

We're looking for free/cheap or open source UML tools. What tools have you used ?
It's OK if there are 2 tools, one each for Flow charts and UML.

If a UML tool or Flow Chart tool is cheap(we're a NON-PROFIT), and no open source is good enough, we're open to look at them.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168512/best-free-professional-looking-uml-tool among many others.

Comment: ^ and the link is dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and easy to use: [JudeUML](http://jude.change-vision.com/jude-web/index.html). There is a free Community Edition.

This software is now released as [astah community](http://astah.change-vision.com/en/product/astah-community.html).

Answer (score 13):

It's online, but I think [yUML](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/draw) is the best free tool I've used. I've used Violet for University work but found it clunky and crash-prone.

*yUml* only supports class diagrams, activity diagrams and use case diagrams though. Here's an example of its output:

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Neat!  Not industrial strength, but perfect for the few small UML-like diagrams I sometimes need to make.  Yay for S.O. and time for idle browsing, otherwise I'd never know about this.

Comment: yUML is great. Take a look at [**GenMyModel**](http://www.genmymodel.com) , same kind of online tool but with code generation.

Answer (score 8):

[StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) is also a nice one

Comment: I like StarUML it's pretty nippy and produces pleasing diagrams. It's a shame that the open source project is somewhat dead due to Delphi falling out of fashion.

Answer (score 7):

I use [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/)

Free, AND open source.

Why i like it : all the diagram have a "sourcecode", for exemple a class is "coded" like that.

```
<<Stereotype>>
Package::FatClass
{Some Properties}
--
-id: Long
-ClassAttribute: Long_
--
#Operation(i: int): int
/+AbstractOperation()/
--
Responsibilities
-- Resp1
-- Resp2
```

It's handy, and avoid heachache with graphical editor.

Edit :
Thanks eric for the precision

Comment: Actually UMLet is opensource:
"Where is the source code?
The source code is in the UMLet zip-file. (There is no makefile, no project file, and no ant-script.)"
http://www.umlet.com/faq.htm

It's a good tool for simple diagrams.

Answer (score 5):

There is for example [DIA](http://live.gnome.org/Dia). Also, [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/) is a commercial UML editor that has a [free community edition](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/editions/community.jsp).

Comment: Visual Paradigm is pretty dern cool.  (And I am using the Community Edition).  Thanks Konamimian.  One Up Vote.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia)

Answer (score 2):

[VioletUML](http://alexdp.free.fr/violetumleditor/page.php) for UML diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

To create flowcharts online, I use [gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com)

Answer (score 1):

[Topcased](http://www.topcased.org/) is integrated to Eclipse and is able to generate code.

Answer (score 0):

ArgoUML could also be an option or, maybe even better, one of the free modeling tools available for the Eclipse enviroment. See: http://modeling-languages.com/content/uml-tools 
for pointers to Eclipse and fre/open-source tools

Answer (score 0):

For BPMN/Workflow I m using [Bizagi Process Modeler](http://www.bizagi.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27&catid=5&Itemid=98).

For UML i m using  [Enterprise architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/index.html) but it is not free but the priceis ok if you look what you get. [Poseidon UML](http://www.gentleware.com/products.html) is ok but suffers when you have a lot of diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [BOUML](http://bouml.free.fr/) before. It is useful for generating Java code from UML class diagrams, if you're into that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

For sketching up sequence diagrams this site is excellent:
http://websequencediagrams.com/

Answer (score 0):

Additional web tools for this task are [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/), [Cacoo](http://cacoo.com/) and [Creately](http://creately.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a few, but hands down winner for me is Topcased. You can get it at [www.topcased.org](http://www.topcased.org).