# What is the best Open Source, linux-compatible UML modeling tool?

Tags: linux, open-source, uml

I've been looking around at the different options, and it seems that even some of the most popular open source tools are Windows-only (StarUML, for example). What is the best open source alternative to programs like Visio and Rational Rose for linux?

Comment: Many, many dupes including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952450/free-cheap-or-open-source-uml-and-visio-like-tool

Comment: It is not a dupe. As I mentioned, in all the other questions (at least all the ones I could find), linux compatibility was not covered.

Comment: Do you mean just "open source" or do you mean "free as in 'free beer' and open source"?

Comment: APC: I mean "open source", although "free as in 'free beer' and open source" is preferable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've used [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/). It does the job.

Comment: +1 because I've used this before too.  Still, it left me wanting something ... better.  I just couldn't find something better at the time.

Comment: I agree, I wasn't exactly bowled over. However, it did handle some kinda tricky stuff decently, like generating code from UML and UML from code. As far as I can tell, the better options are commercial products. Over all, ArgoUML did what I needed it to.

Comment: It does not support UML 2.x and that is sad

Answer (score 5):

- [Eclipse Modelling tools](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2) supports UML
- [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia/UML%20Tutorial) also supports UML

Comment: I like dia as well.  Though it lacks some features you'd expect in a modeling tool, I think modeling is more like an advanced form of doodling on a napkin and so I think all the code generation features and such tend to get in the way and be irritating.

Comment: Please, DIA is unusable. I've used it in a number of occasions because of somebody else's decision but it's really unusable. It could be with a few minor changes (like the z-ordering) but the way it is it's painful.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Umbrello](http://uml.sourceforge.net/) on a number of small projects and it seems to work well enough.

Answer (score -3):

The best I found was [ganttproject](http://www.ganttproject.biz/). It's quite good IMO.