# What are some free online flow chart tools?

Tags: private, flowchart

Can somebody tell me of a tool that helps draw a flow chart online (to collaborate) but not make it public. I did see [free, cheap or open source UML and Visio-like tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952450) that talks of gliffy but it makes charts public in the free mode.

Answer (score 3):

Eh... I'd just use `vim` + `graphviz` + `git`, but that's just me.

Answer (score 2):

This was recommended to me: Web Sequence Diagrams.

http://www.websequencediagrams.com/

HTH

Comment: Nice tool for a very specific job but pretty expensive at $9 per month for the single user version.

Answer (score 2):

Bumping an old Q - but:

Have found this one to be very nice for ASCII flow charts:

http://www.asciiflow.com

Some highlights:

- Select area and drag it around.
- Write text.
- Select area copy and paste it anywhere.
- Export / Import.
- Public edit and read only links.

Downside:

- Do not support drawing by key-board.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a free online tool:

https://ludoaubert.github.io/linkedboxdraw/README.html

You can start by reading the README. One key principle is that you keep your info private, it never gets uploaded.

For reverse engineering SQL schemas, of course the reverse engineered diagram will look a lot better if foreign keys are implemented :)

https://ludoaubert.github.io/linkedboxdraw/table_edit_ti.html